# Java, Archivos al sobrescribirse crean un caos

Tags: java, netbeans, archivo, netbeans-8.1

Resulta que tengo este código aquí, en el cual estoy tratando de manejar un inventario por archivos
Pasa que, al modificar y guardar uno de los artículos el .txt se vuelve un completo desastre.

Este es el .txt en su estado antes de la modificación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el .txt después de la modificación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
case 6: //Guardar
                    try{
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ar));
                        System.out.println("Archivo modificado con exito.");
                        for(Proyecto_Inventario n:lista){
                          bw.write(n.getNombre()+"\t"
                                  +n.getPrecio()+"\t"
                                  +n.getDesc()+"\t"
                                  +n.getCant()+"\t"
                                  +n.getAlm()); 
                      }
                      bw.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
                    break;
```

Esta de aquí es la opción que sobrescribe el archivo.

Comment: Te falta agregar un salto de línea después del almacén: `+n.getAlm()+"\n”);`

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si estas agregando las propiedades de cada objeto separadas por tabulador pero cada objeto lo deseas agregar en un renglón diferente, debes agregar al final una nueva linea mediante `"\n"`,  esto después de agregar las propiedades de cada objeto:

```
               ...
               ...
               for(Proyecto_Inventario n:lista){
                      bw.write(n.getNombre()+"\t"
                              +n.getPrecio()+"\t"
                              +n.getDesc()+"\t"
                              +n.getCant()+"\t"
                              +n.getAlm() + "\n"); 
                  }
                ...
                ...
```

de esta forma obtendrías como resultado las propiedades de cada objeto en un renglon diferente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]